# Windows Server 2019 - lost all computer from OU?

Tags: entra-id, windows-server-2019, organizational-unit

I keep computer accounts (Computers) in two separate OU units in Active Directory structure. This morning I had to add some users, and noticed that all machines are missing from their corresponding OU.

When I searched, they were found, but I can't see them anywhere else.

What should I do to amend this?

Comment: As the answer explains this was just a temporary glitch and thus does not warrant long term storage on this site.

Comment: Agreed; delete it pls.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found it. - This was a temporary glitch; I was able to see all computers in OUS after I right clicked, and selected filter to show all resources. It repopulated everything then.